# Saving XML File with c# and keep the format of empty element

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to figure out how I can keep the XML format intact.

Ex)

I have an empty element that when I save the file to a new file it adds the element like so:

```
<typeOfBackup></typeOfBackup>
```

Instead I want it to save like:

```
<typeOfBackup/>
```

My code:

```
XmlDocument myXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
myXmlDocument.Load(@"C:\t1.xml");

XmlNode node;
node = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement;


myXmlDocument.Save(@"C:\t2.xml");
```

Comment: Why does it matter to you? The two are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should keep your whitespace the way you want it.

```
 myXmlDocument.Save(@"C:\t2.xml", SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Comment: SaveOptions is not available.

Comment: SaveOptions is available on XElement - part of the system.xml.linq namespace. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions.aspx. You may need to make some code changes to use it.